# Unable to enable curl on opensuse aws

Tags: curl, opensuse

I am trying to enable curl on opensuse ec2 instance on aws. 
I setup the apache,php mysql using below commands

```
- zypper in apache2
- zypper in php5 php5-mysql php5-curl php5-soap php5-zip php5-pcntl php-mbstring apache2-mod_php5
- zypper in mysql mysql-tools
- chkconfig apache2 on
- chkconfig mysql on
- SuSEconfig
- service apache2 restart
- service mysql restart
```

When I run php -i | grep curl command I get

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php5/extensions/php_curl.dll' - /usr/lib64/php5/extensions/php_curl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php5/extensions/php_openssl.dll' - /usr/lib64/php5/extensions/php_openssl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/bin/curl' - /usr/bin/curl: cannot dynamically load executable in Unknown on line 0
/etc/php5/conf.d/curl.ini,

When I run grep `-Hrv ";" /etc/php5 | grep -i "extension="` I get following message.

```
/etc/php5/conf.d/mbstring.ini:extension=mbstring.so
/etc/php5/conf.d/ctype.ini:extension=ctype.so
/etc/php5/conf.d/iconv.ini:extension=iconv.so
/etc/php5/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini:extension=pdo_mysql.so
/etc/php5/conf.d/dom.ini:extension=dom.so
/etc/php5/conf.d/mysql.ini:extension=mysql.so
/etc/php5/conf.d/tokenizer.ini:extension=tokenizer.so
/etc/php5/conf.d/mysqli.ini:extension=mysqli.so
/etc/php5/conf.d/pdo.ini:extension=pdo.so
/etc/php5/conf.d/zlib.ini:extension=zlib.so
/etc/php5/conf.d/xmlwriter.ini:extension=xmlwriter.so
/etc/php5/conf.d/curl.ini:extension= /usr/bin/curl
/etc/php5/conf.d/json.ini:extension=json.so
/etc/php5/conf.d/xmlreader.ini:extension=xmlreader.so
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini: extension=/usr/bin/curl.so
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini:extension=php_openssl.dll
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini:extension=php_curl.dll
```

I was not able to find the curl.so file. I think it should be in extension folder where zlib.so, xmlwrite.so files are.

Please help me to find a way to run curl.

THanks